# How to show 'typing' text when users typing in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am working in a vue project where i need to show 'typing' or 'loading' text when user typing in placeholder please help me to do so

Comment: Are you building a chat?

Comment: please add more details and the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Actually a dashboard and i am trying to add chat with admin feature and above requirement is needed for chat section and a search bar where user can search for admins and in some other search bar too

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is most easily achieved by setting some boolean = true on the `@input` event (so whenever a user is typing) and then setting the boolean back to false when typing has stopped.  Bind the boolean to conditionally display some text "is typing..." under the input whenever the boolean is true.

You usually want to [debounce](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/) the boolean being set to false to allow some time between keystrokes so the boolean is only set false once all typing is done.  You can code your own debounce or use a library.  I've provided an example below of this feature using the debounce function provided by [lodash](https://lodash.com/):

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <input @input="startTyping" />
    <div>
      <small v-if="isTyping">User is typing...</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import debounce from "lodash/debounce";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isTyping: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    startTyping() {
      this.isTyping = true;
      this.debounceStopTyping();
    },
    debounceStopTyping: debounce(function () {
      this.isTyping = false;
    }, 500),
  },
};
</script>
```